# How to reslove this deadlock situation with pthread_mutex

Tags: c++, c, linux, pthreads, mutex

I have a piece of code that is protected by a Mutex

```
pthread_mutex_lock(&Mutex1);
write(fid,data_buffer,size);
pthread_mutex_unlock(&Mutex1);
```

This can be called by at most two functions: `func1()` and `func2()`. However the mutex'd `write()` may not always return  - i.e it waits on certain conditions to occur before it returns. So if `func1()` calls `write()` and it does not return then the mutex is never unlocked and `func2()` is never able to call `write()`. Is there a way to force the release of the mutex if `write()` never returns to avoid this deadlock? Maybe there is another option other than mutex?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you need a different/better write function instead.

Comment: You probably want to use non-blocking I/O in that case.

Comment: If your `write()` really never returns under some circumstances, then you must not perform it under protection of a mutex (under those circumstances).  Your options are to protect it some other way or not at all, or to ensure that it will eventually return.  We cannot suggest any details without a more complete description of the problem, preferrably in the form of a [mcve].

Comment: System calls like write() are thread-safe.  They don't need mutex protection.  If your particular application requires 'atomic' writes that are not interrupted, for some reason, then use a producer-consumer queue to queue the write request struct/class instances to a single write thread.

Comment: First of all  i agree with @NathanOliver you should move lock to write function and keep it only for critical section and separate it  from block condition, If you cant reffer to  pthread_mutex_timedlock

Comment: You seem to need a condition variable inside write. But first you need to move the mutex inside write and show us its code so we can help.